# Helm - change key evaluation in running time

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to figure out a way to change a key name from 'values-file', in running time.

This is my values-file: values-version.yaml

```
services:
  - name: service1
  - name: service2
  - name: service3
```

I call it from template configMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-confmap
data:
    ### This is the part I am trying to implement:
    ### if 'name of list' == 'services' -> change 'name of list' to services1
    {{- range $service := .Values.services1 }}
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/{{ $service1.name }}-*_platform*.log
    {{- end }}
```

I did not find a way implement it with "sprig" but would like to get any advices.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the use-case for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "name of list"?  Can you edit the question so the `service`, `service1`, and `services` are consistent (the `.Values.name` should match the top-level YAML key; the `$service` local variable name should be consistent)?